# LINQ query to sort list of numeric strings with NULLs

Tags: string, linq, numeric

I have a list of strings:

```
6, 5, 11, 1, 10, 3, NULL, NULL
```

I need a LINQ query to sort/orderby so I get this:

```
1, 5, 6, 10, 11, NULL, NULL
```

I don't want to convert the list.  This almost works:

```
list myList = myList.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

But the NULLs break it.  I'm sure this is easy, but TIA.

- Using C#

Comment: have you maybe just try somthing like: list myList = myList.Where(item=>item!=null).OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList(); OR  list myList = myList.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x ?? 0)).ToList();

Comment: Why you use strings instead of `int?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you maybe just try something like:

```
list myList = myList.Where(item=>item!=null).OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

OR

```
list myList = myList.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x ?? 0)).ToList();
```

Comment: Your first suggestion is what I would have though, but I get an exception:  "Input string was not in a correct format".

Comment: Ugh, same with the second way.  Not sure what's going on :(

Comment: mmm can you check double the values inside your list? .. are your sure the values are 6, 5, 11, 1, 10, 3, NULL, NULL ??

Comment: When I say NULL, I mean an **empty string**.

Comment: I'm such a dumbass.  Once I changed the " == null" to " == string.empty" it worked fine.  Thank you for all your help @federico :)

Comment: you can also put !String.IsNullOrEmpty() so you check in one shot for null and empty string

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] xs = new[] { "6", "5", "11", "1", "10", "3", null, null };
IOrderedEnumerable<string> myList = xs.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x ?? $"{int.MaxValue}")).ToList();
```

As you want `null`s to be after numbers use just max int value for this case. As your value type is `string` then use interpolated string to pass `int.MaxValue` as a string.

`??` returns right expression in the case when the left expression evaluates to `null`.

Interpolated strings are very neat .Net feature: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx.

You could also use `string.IsNullOrEmpty`, `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, or `int.TryParse` then `int.Parse`, in your query, depending on your data, in order to guarantee successful parsing (and hence ordering) of all elements.